# React-native expo Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to build a phone app for an assignment that uses a map, I'm trying to make my own component and use it on my screen.

Originally I made my component on a separate file and tried to use it from there but I kept getting this error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `MapComponent`.
```

So I checked the internet for answers and found many, but ultimately they mentioned I should use curly braces when importing the component. I've tried every combination of curly brackets but so far no luck. Then I move the component entirely to the screen file and removed the `export default` keywords from the class and used it there. Still the same error.

I've also seen someone mention the inclusion of `super();` in the consturctor, no luck. Also someone said I should include the `component` parent class from the  `React` library instead of `react-native`, still no luck.

I'm stuck and I don't know what to do. I'm using expo version `50.0.8`, npm: `9.5.1` version and working on windows.

Here is my code:

Map.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { SafeAreaView, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, Image, View, Text,   AppRegistry,
  ScrollView,
  Animated,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import ImageButton from '../components/ImageButton';

const Images = [
  ...
]

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

const CARD_HEIGHT = height / 4;
const CARD_WIDTH = CARD_HEIGHT - 50;

class Map extends Component {
  state = {
    markers: [
      ...
    ],
    region: {
      ...
    },
  };

  constructor(){
    super();
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.index = 0;
    this.animation = new Animated.Value(0);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.animation.addListener(({ value }) => {
      let index = Math.floor(value / CARD_WIDTH + 0.3); 
      if (index >= this.state.markers.length) {
        index = this.state.markers.length - 1;
      }
      if (index <= 0) {
        index = 0;
      }

      clearTimeout(this.regionTimeout);
      this.regionTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.index !== index) {
          this.index = index;
          const { coordinate } = this.state.markers[index];
          this.map.animateToRegion(
            {
              ...coordinate,
              latitudeDelta: this.state.region.latitudeDelta,
              longitudeDelta: this.state.region.longitudeDelta,
            },
            350
          );
        }
      }, 10);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const interpolations = this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => {
      const inputRange = [
        (index - 1) * CARD_WIDTH,
        index * CARD_WIDTH,
        ((index + 1) * CARD_WIDTH),
      ];
      const scale = this.animation.interpolate({
        inputRange,
        outputRange: [1, 2.5, 1],
        extrapolate: "clamp",
      });
      const opacity = this.animation.interpolate({
        inputRange,
        outputRange: [0.35, 1, 0.35],
        extrapolate: "clamp",
      });
      return { scale, opacity };
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          ref={map => this.map = map}
          initialRegion={this.state.region}
          style={styles.container}
        >
          {this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => {
            const scaleStyle = {
              transform: [
                {
                  scale: interpolations[index].scale,
                },
              ],
            };
            const opacityStyle = {
              opacity: interpolations[index].opacity,
            };
            return (
              <MapView.Marker key={index} coordinate={marker.coordinate}>
                <Animated.View style={[styles.markerWrap, opacityStyle]}>
                  <Animated.View style={[styles.ring, scaleStyle]} />
                  <View style={styles.marker} />
                </Animated.View>
              </MapView.Marker>
            );
          })}
        </MapView>
        <Animated.ScrollView
          horizontal
          scrollEventThrottle={1}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          snapToInterval={CARD_WIDTH}
          onScroll={Animated.event(
            [
              {
                nativeEvent: {
                  contentOffset: {
                    x: this.animation,
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
            { useNativeDriver: true }
          )}
          style={styles.scrollView}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.endPadding}
        >
          {this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => (
            <View style={styles.card} key={index}>
              <Image
                source={marker.image}
                style={styles.cardImage}
                resizeMode="cover"
              />
              <View style={styles.textContent}>
                <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.cardtitle}>{marker.title}</Text>
                <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.cardDescription}>
                  {marker.description}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          ))}
        </Animated.ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


function MapScreen() 
{
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
          return;
        }
  
        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setLocation(location.coords);
      })();
    }, []);


  
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <ImageButton
                customStyle = {styles.backButton}
                source={require('../assets/back.png')}
                onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('MainHub');}}
            />
        {location ? (
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#000000" />
          ) : (
            <Map/>
                )}
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

// Styles here

export default MapScreen;
```

And my App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';


import MapScreen from "./app/screens/MapScreen";
...


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Loading">
        <Stack.Screen name="Loading" component={LoadScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="MapScreen" component={MapScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
...
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The error code is  the same as above, it just says `Check the render method of 'Map'.` at the end instead.